# How to get newest SDK version for Buildozer

Tags: android, sdk, kivy, buildozer

I rebuilt Ubuntu and I don't have my old SDK files. I used `~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android` in my terminal to try downloading them via the SDK manager (as seen in the picture shows) but I only see the SDK targeting APIs of 19 and lower.

How do I get the latest SDK? Thank you in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the SDK inside of the .buildozer file, then changed `android.sdk = 23` in buildozer.spec. It appears that buildozer automatically downloads the specified sdk.